# Laravel 6 id change after sort by relationship

Tags: laravel, join

I don't know how to explain it...

On Tinker:

```
$m = App\Models\Mobiliari::Buscar('5')
$m->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3038
     all: [
       App\Models\Mobiliari {#3051
         id: "5",
         entitat_id: "3",
         tipus_mobiliari_id: "2",
         descripcio: null,
         data_compra: null,
         proveidor_id: "2",
         factura: null,
         cost: ".0000",
         ubicacio_id: "2",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Buscar is a function to filter on some fields:

```
public function scopeBuscar($query, $filtre)
    {
        if ($filtre)
        {
            return $query->where('mobiliari.id', $filtre)
                ->orWhere('descripcio', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%')
                ->orWhereHas('Entitat', function($q) use ($filtre) {
                    $q->where('entitat', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%');
                })
                ->orWhereHas('TipusMobiliari', function($q) use ($filtre) {
                    $q->where('tipus', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%');
                })
                ->orWhereHas('Proveidor', function($q) use ($filtre) {
                    $q->where('proveidor', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%');
                })
                ->orWhereHas('Ubicacio', function($q) use ($filtre) {
                    $q->where('edifici', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%')
                        ->orWhere('ubicacio', 'like', '%'.$filtre.'%');
                });
        }
    }
```

Then, when try to order the result through a related table, the ID change te value

```
$m->join('entitat', 'mobiliari.entitat_id', '=', 'entitat.id')->orderBy('entitat.entitat','asc')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3041
     all: [
       App\Models\Mobiliari {#3040
         id: "3",
         entitat_id: "3",
         tipus_mobiliari_id: "2",
         descripcio: null,
         data_compra: null,
         proveidor_id: "2",
         factura: null,
         cost: ".0000",
         ubicacio_id: "2",
         entitat: "UAB Idiomes",
         rao_social: "Escola d'Idiomes Moderns Casa Convalescència SL",
       },
     ],
   }
```

I captured the query generated with DB::enableQueryLog(); and dd(DB::getQueryLog()), executed it on de SQL Server and returns the correct ID...

Anyone knows or can explain why ID is changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are joining tables, the id can be ambiguous and the `Laravel` ORM will take one of the id even from your joins.

Adding select() with your current table will help your problem. You can still select extra columns if you need, but if using ids from other tables rename the columns in the `SQL`.

```
->select('mobiliari.*');
```

So try the following code.

```
$m->join('entitat', 'mobiliari.entitat_id', '=', 'entitat.id')
    ->orderBy('entitat.entitat','asc')
    ->select('mobiliari.*')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Works fine! But still surprised about... Why SQL Server runs query well and Eloquent change the value?

Comment: Because the result will be mobiliari.id 1 entitat.id 2 and then eloquent dont know which id to take :)